# How to create a complete sphere from pydata?

Tags: python, mesh

I want to create a sphere from a 2D array of data. I've gotten quite close except I can't figure out how to close the sphere.

```
polygons = [(i, i - 1, i - 1 + xsize, i + xsize) for i in range( 1, len(verts) - xsize )  if i % xsize != 0]

m.from_pydata(verts,[],polygons)
```

But it doesn't close the edges.
[image]

I've tried adding these polygons

```
polygons += [(i,  (i*xsize)-1 , i*xsize, (i*2*xsize) -1 ) for i in range(1,ysize-2)]
```

This looks like this before coordinate converting

```
[863   0   0] [1 0 0] [863   1   0] [0 1 0]
[863   1   0] [2 0 0] [863   3   0] [0 2 0]
[863   2   0] [3 0 0] [863   5   0] [0 3 0]
```

As you can see it's the first and last coordinates of the 2D array.
But adding this does nothing.

Is there an operation about merging or connecting these vertices?

Comment: Yes. There has operation to merging vertices:  ➤bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.0001, use_unselected=False, use_sharp_edge_from_normals=False) ➤bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts, dist)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. And my understanding is this removes doubles by distance which wouldn't fix this problem.